# nginx-container + git doesn't work anymore

Tags: git, docker, nginx

I have a nginx-container as a reverse-proxy on my server. I used the server for git. I splitted the nginx-conf-file into multiple files and included all the files into default.conf-file. Then I rebuild the nginx-container and started it.After this I coudn't pull a repository.

The git-repository are on the server under the following path:

- /mnt/bigdata/git/

This path exists in the nginx-container aswell and is mounted to the server.

My nginx-conf looked like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name mySite.de;
    include snippets/ssl-mySite.de;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    location /git(/.*) {

        root /mnt/bigdata/git;

        client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
        auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
        auth_basic_user_file "/mnt/bigdata/git/htpasswd";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /mnt/bigdata/git; # /mnt/bigdata/git is the location of all of your git repositories.
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; # Pass the request to fastcgi
    }
}
```

I got the following error in my nginx logs:

```
2018/03/03 20:44:16 [error] 20#20: *1 open() "/etc/nginx/html/git/Testing.git/info/refs" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 135.21.244.72, server: mySite.de, request: "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "mySite.de"
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:44:16 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
```

So nginx is trying to open /etc/nginx/html/git... . It seem's like the root command doesn't have any effect. I changed the nginx-conf to the following:

```
...
root /mnt/bigdata/git;
location /git(/.*) {
client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
...
```

nginx error:

```
2018/03/03 20:49:33 [error] 20#20: *1 open() "/mnt/bigdata/git/git/Testing.git/info/refs" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 135.21.244.72, server: mySite.de, request: "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1", host: "mySite.de"
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:49:33 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 169 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
```

Ok /mnt/bigdata/git/git... doesn't exists so I have to delete the /git tag and changed it to:

```
...
root /mnt/bigdata;
location /git(/.*) {
client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
...
```

nginx-logs:

```
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:51:53 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:51:53 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
```

This time I could clone the repository to my computer. But the repository is empty:

```
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

Thats not true. If I look in Testing.git folder on the server I can see multiple packs. Now I added a file to the empty folder and tried to push it to the server. I get the following error on the terminal:

```
error: Cannot access URL https://mySite.de/git/Testing.git/, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://mySite.de/git/Testing.git'
```

nginx-logs:

```
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:54:37 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:54:37 +0000] "GET /git/Testing.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
135.21.244.72 - - [03/Mar/2018:20:54:37 +0000] "PROPFIND /git/Testing.git/ HTTP/1.1" 405 173 "-" "git/2.7.4" "-"
```

nginx-dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.13
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/snippets
RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/conf-files
RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/certs/
RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/mySite.de/
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/bigdata/git
VOLUME [ "/etc/nginx/conf-files", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/mySite.de/","/etc/ssl/certs/","/etc/conf.d/","/etc/nginx/snippets/","/mnt/bigdata/git" ]
COPY start-nginx.sh .
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano spawn-fcgi fcgiwrap wget curl apache2-utils git
RUN sed -i 's/www-data/nginx/g' /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap
RUN chown nginx:nginx /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap
RUN mkdir /scripts
ADD scripts/ /scripts
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

CMD /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap start \
    && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

***Changing the conf-file from nginx back to my old one fixed the problem. But I need to use the nginx-conf with the includes!***

**My old nginx-conf:**

```
upstream jenkins {
  server 45.3.35.321:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream docker-jira {
    server jira:8080;
}

upstream docker-conf {
        server conf:8090;
}

upstream docker-orchestra {
    server orchestra:8080;
}
upstream docker-orchestra-port {
    server orchestra;
}
server {
    listen 8443;
    listen 8444;
    listen 8019;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://docker-orchestra-port:$server_port;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name mySite.de;
    return 301 https://mySite.de;
}


server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name mySite.de;

    include snippets/ssl-mySite.de;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


    location  ~ /git(/.*) {
        root /mnt/bigdata/git;
        client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
        auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
        auth_basic_user_file "/mnt/bigdata/git/htpasswd";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /mnt/bigdata/git; # /var/www/git is the location of all of your git repositories.
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; # Pass the request to fastcgi
    }

    location /jenkins {
            proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass              http://jenkins;
            proxy_redirect      http://jenkins $scheme://mySite.de;
            # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
            # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
            add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.domain.tld:50022' always;
            client_max_body_size 2M;
    }


        location /orchestra {

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_pass http://docker-orchestra/orchestra;

                proxy_redirect http://docker-orchestra/orchestra https://mySite.de/orchestra;

                client_max_body_size 100M;

                add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        }

    location /jira {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://docker-jira/jira;

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW;

    }

    location /confluence {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://docker-conf/confluence;

        proxy_redirect http://docker-conf/confluence https://mySite.de;     

        client_max_body_size 100M;

        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    }

    location /synchrony {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://mySite.de:8091/synchrony;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        client_max_body_size 100M;

    }

}
```

**My new not working nginx-conf:**

```
include /etc/nginx/conf-files/jira-confluence-upstream.conf;
include /etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-upstream.conf;

upstream jenkins {
  server 45.3.35.321:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    server_name mySite.de;
    return 301 https://mySite.de;
}

include /etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-ports.conf;

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name mySite.de;

    include snippets/ssl-mySite.de;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location /git(/.*) {

        root /mnt/bigdata/git;

        client_max_body_size 0; # Git pushes can be massive, just to make sure nginx doesn't suddenly cut the connection add this.
        auth_basic "Git Login"; # Whatever text will do.
        auth_basic_user_file "/mnt/bigdata/git/htpasswd";
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params; # Include the default fastcgi configs
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend; # Tells fastcgi to pass the request to the git http backend executable
        fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
        fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /mnt/bigdata/git; # /mnt/bigdata/git is the location of all of your git repositories.
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1; # Takes the capture group from our location directive and gives git that.
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket; # Pass the request to fastcgi
    }

        location /jenkins {
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_pass              http://jenkins;
                    proxy_redirect      http://jenkins $scheme://mySite.de;
                    # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_request_buffering off;
                    proxy_buffering off; # Required for HTTP-based CLI to work over SSL
                    # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
                    add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.domain.tld:50022' always;
        }

        include /etc/nginx/conf-files/jira-confluence-location.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-location.conf;

}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf-files/jira-confluence-upstream.conf:**

```
upstream docker-jira {
    server jira:8080;
}

upstream docker-conf {
        server conf:8090;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-upstream.conf:**

```
upstream docker-orchestra {
    server orchestra:8080;
}
upstream docker-orchestra-port {
    server orchestra;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-ports.conf:**

```
server {
    listen 8443;
    listen 8444;
    listen 8019;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://docker-orchestra-port:$server_port;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf-files/jira-confluence-location.conf:**

```
location /jira {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://docker-jira/jira;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    add_header X-Frame-Options ALLOW;

}

location /confluence {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://docker-conf/confluence;

    proxy_redirect http://docker-conf/confluence https://MySite.de;     

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

}

location /synchrony {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
```

**/etc/nginx/conf-files/orchestra-location.conf:**

```
location /orchestra {

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_pass http://docker-orchestra/orchestra;

            proxy_redirect http://docker-orchestra/orchestra https://MySite.de/orchestra;

            client_max_body_size 100M;

            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to go in the git-repository on the server and run:

```
sudo git update-server-info
```

and change

```
location /git(/.*) {
```

to

```
location ~ /git(/.*) {
```